# Case when missing line logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a case when statement in a extract query which doesn't seem to be returning what i'm expecting

```
DECLARE @Val1 int, @Val2 int,@Val3 int, @Val4 int, @Val5 int

SELECT  @Val1 = 5 , @Val2= 2,@Val3= 200000, @Val5  = 2,@Val4 = 2014
SELECT  @Val1 , @Val2,@Val3, @Val4, @Val5   

SELECT CASE

        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NULL  THEN 'ReturnValue1'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ReturnValue2'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  = 2 AND @Val3 = 200000  AND @Val5 = 2 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ReturnValue3'
        ELSE NULL
    END [TestingValue]
```

I'm expecting the value to be ReturnValue3 however it appears to be ignoring this whole line for some reason.

Can anyone see a problem which I'm not spotting.

Comment: And gives you `'ReturnValue2'` as result, because the 2nd condition is true?: `WHEN @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ReturnValue2'`

Comment: This has been cross-posted on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703156/case-when-not-returning-correct-data If you feel that DBA.SE is a better fit for this question then you should flag it for mod attention asking that they move it to an appropriate site.

Answer (score 3):

Your second clause is triggering as true before your third clause and as such your third clause does not get evaluated - CASE WHEN returns the **first** TRUE value as opposed to the last TRUE value

`@Val1 = 5` TRUE

`@Val2  IN(1,2)` TRUE

`@Val3 = 200000` TRUE

`@Val4 IS NOT NULL` TRUE

Comment: Thanks, I had notice if I moved the statement to the top then it work fine, but thought I was missing something else.